# C - Cursor placement influencing program

Tags: c, string, terminal, io

I'm writing a C program that reads a string in the form of a table from a *.txt* file, counts rows and columns in it and prints the table to a different *.txt* file.

Here's the input table:

```
Something.Something-Something
Something.Something-Something
Something.Something-Something
Something.Something-Something
```

Here's how I run the program:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o main main.c
./main <tabin.txt >tabout.txt
```

The program itself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define ROW_LENGTH 10240

int rowNumber(char buffer[ROW_LENGTH], int i, int rowcounter) {
    if(buffer[i] == '\n')
        ++rowcounter;
    return rowcounter;
}

int colNumber(char buffer[ROW_LENGTH], int i, int colcounter) {
    if(!isalnum(buffer[i]))
        ++colcounter;
    return colcounter;
}

int main() {
    char buffer[ROW_LENGTH];
    int rowcounter = 0;
    int colcounter = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer, ROW_LENGTH, stdin) != NULL)
        for(int i = 0; buffer[i]; i++) {
            rowcounter = rowNumber(buffer, i, rowcounter);
            colcounter = colNumber(buffer, i, colcounter);
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        }

    printf("\n%d", rowcounter);
    printf("\n%d", colcounter);

    return 0;
}
```

And know the part I don't understand. I'm using CLion on Ubuntu. When I place the cursor right after the last g and save, I get

```
3
11
```

However when place the cursor on the first character of the next line, I get

```
4
12
```

What are the ways I can change my code so cursor position doesn't influence the results I get?

Comment: What is this 'last g' you speak of?

Comment: I guess in one case the last few chars in your file are `"omething"<EOF>` and `"omething\n"<EOF>` in the other. (`<EOF>` is not a char, that's the reason it's outside the quotes). BTW, I like t think the lines with `'\n'` are standard, lines without are "quasi-lines" (though they are common in Windows land)

Comment: Are you expecting that your file might contain single lines of around 10240 characters or more?  The only reason you should be checking your buffer for the existence of `\n` is if you fully expect that you have to read a single line in multiple chunks.  Otherwise, it's quite okay to assume that every call to `fgets` returns one line.  But if you want to do it this way, that's fine.  You'll just need to add some more convoluted logic to what you already have.  Seems a bit ridiculous to me.  The root of the issue is if there's no newline on the last line in the file, it won't be in your buffer.

Comment: @paddy thanks, makes sense now. What could be the way I get the newline to the buffer?

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  If there is no newline to read, then that's that.  Why do you insist on this archaic method of counting lines?  And what is stopping you from simply checking if the buffer is non-empty and contains no newline after the loop, then incrementing your count?

Comment: You could initialize a variable in `main`, `int lastch = '\n';`. Then, inside the `for` loop, set `lastch = buffer[i];`. Then, after the end of the `while` loop, check `if (lastch != '\n')` and take some appropriate action.